# Trouble with Shell Script cat | grep

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, cat

```
#!/bin/bash
mylanip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
touch /opt/portmapper/0prelims
echo `java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -list | grep $mylanip > /opt/portmapper/0prelims`
# HTTPS
portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:443 | awk '{print $4}')
if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:443 ]; then
    echo "Nothing Altered for HTTPS"
fi
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:443 ]; then
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -delete -protocol TCP -internalPort 443 -externalPort 443  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 443 -externalPort 443 -ip $mylanip -description HTTPS >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    echo "Added port forwarding for HTTPS"
fi
# Private TTY
portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:57 | awk '{print $4}')
if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:57 ]; then
    echo "Nothing Altered for Private TTY"
fi
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:57 ]; then
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -delete -protocol TCP -internalPort 57 -externalPort 57  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 57 -externalPort 57 -ip $mylanip -description PrivateTTY  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    echo "Added port forwarding for Private TTY"
fi
# HTTP
 portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:80 | awk '{print $4}')

if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:80 ]; then
    echo "Nothing Altered for HTTP"
fi
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:80 ]; then
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -delete -protocol TCP -internalPort 80 -externalPort 80 >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 80 -externalPort 80 -ip $mylanip -description HTTP  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
    echo "Added port forwarding for HTTP"
fi
exit
```

How do I only get the 443 line and not the 4433 line? its entering both into the variable for checking. If I manually do the string it places the string below into the variable.

10.0.0.30:443 10.0.0.30:4433

Here is my ending output repeatedly:

```
Added port forwarding for HTTPS
Nothing Altered for PrivateTTY
Nothing Altered for HTTP
```

here is an excerpt from my 0prelims

```
12:45:43.322 [main] INFO  o.f.cling.transport.spi.StreamServer - Created server (for receiving TCP streams) on: /10.0.0.30:44725
12:45:43.324 [main] INFO  o.f.cling.transport.spi.DatagramIO - Creating bound socket (for datagram input/output) on: /10.0.0.30
TCP :7881 -> 10.0.0.30:7881 enabled Deluge 1.3.12 at 10.0.0.30:7881
TCP :4433 -> 10.0.0.30:4433 enabled Deluge 1.3.12 at 10.0.0.30:4433
UDP :7881 -> 10.0.0.30:7881 enabled Deluge 1.3.12 at 10.0.0.30:7881
TCP :57 -> 10.0.0.30:57 enabled PrivateTTY
TCP :443 -> 10.0.0.30:443 enabled HTTPS
TCP :80 -> 10.0.0.30:80 enabled HTTP
```

Answer (score 1):

Output of your script on [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/). Correct the problems:

```
Line 4:
echo `java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -list | grep $mylanip > /opt/portmapper/0prelims`
     ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
     ^-- SC2005: Useless echo? Instead of 'echo $(cmd)', just use 'cmd'.
     ^-- SC2006: Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                                                            ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 6:
portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:443 | awk '{print $4}')
                 ^-- SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.
                                                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 7:
if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:443 ]; then
                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 10:
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:443 ]; then
                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 12:
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 443 -externalPort 443 -ip $mylanip -description HTTPS >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
                                                                                                                                                                ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 16:
portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:57 | awk '{print $4}')
                 ^-- SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.
                                                 ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 17:
if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:57 ]; then
                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 20:
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:57 ]; then
                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 22:
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 57 -externalPort 57 -ip $mylanip -description PrivateTTY  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
                                                                                                                                                              ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 26:
 portprelim=$(cat /opt/portmapper/0prelims | grep ${mylanip}:80 | awk '{print $4}')
                  ^-- SC2002: Useless cat. Consider 'cmd < file | ..' or 'cmd file | ..' instead.
                                                  ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 28:
if [ "$portprelim" = $mylanip:80 ]; then
                     ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 31:
if [ "$portprelim" != $mylanip:80 ]; then
                      ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 33:
    java -jar /opt/portmapper/portmapper.jar -lib org.chris.portmapper.router.sbbi.SBBIRouterFactory -add -protocol TCP -internalPort 80 -externalPort 80 -ip $mylanip -description HTTP  >/dev/null ; sleep 2 ;
                                                                                                                                                              ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
grep ${mylanip}:443
```

do

```
grep "${mylanip}:443 "
```

so the whitespace after 443 get part if the search expression.

Comment: Quoting treats it as exact text. Turns the string yellow and does not express the variable.